# C# - NotifyIcon if textbox.text = "hello"

Tags: c#, notifyicon

I want to show a notifyicon if for this code:

```
if (textbox.text == "hello");
```

Anyone have an idea on how i can do this?

Comment: I don't understand your question. Please clarify it..

Comment: Is it ASP.net or winforms application ?

Answer (score 0):

Check this link

[Notify Icon In C# Form](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/mahesh/notify-icon-in-C-Sharp/)

This code worked for me(set on a button click)

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (textBox1.Text == "hello")
        {
            notifyIcon1.BalloonTipText = "hi";
            notifyIcon1.ShowBalloonTip(100);
        }
    }
```

Remember to add an icon to the notifyicon element.

Answer (score 0):

It looks something like this probably.

```
if (textBox1.Text.ToLower() == "hello")
   notifyIcon1.Visible = true;
else
   notifyIcon1.Visible = false;
```

it shows and hides the notificationicon control

NOTE: add this to an event if you want it to perform automatically or call it explicitly using a method.